# How to convert a HTML Table in an MVC View to PDF file, ITextSharp

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I've been pointed in the direction of ITextSharp, when I went to download the package from NuGet I noticed something called RazorToPDF only to discover unsolvable formatting issues due to the project no longer being supported.

After more research I was surprised to find there wasn't a similarly worded question as this on SO.

So guys, what's the best way to convert a HTML page/table in an MVC project to a PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to convert a HTML page/table in an MVC project to a PDF file?

Generally, print it to a PDF from the web browser on the client.

The thing is, by relying on the end-user perspective of the view in this case, you're also relying on the end-user rendering of that view.  It's a step that should be removed from this particular equation entirely.

Keep in mind that there are fundamental differences between how an HTML page renders and how a PDF renders.  The two aren't 100% interchangeable.  A PDF has a static page size and elements are placed absolutely, whereas HTML has dynamic sizes and elements are placed in a flow layout.  There are additional considerations such as client-side DOM manipulation that may take place in that view.  "Rendering" it quickly becomes a browser-based activity, which is something you shouldn't really need to do server-side.

Instead of thinking of the PDF as an extra step following the rendering of the view, think of it as a view in and or itself, parallel to the other view.  One requested action results in the HTML view, another requested action results in the PDF "view".  As such, you design the PDF template how you want it to look and populate it with data (using something like iTextSharp) before returning the file contents to the client.

Comment: "design the PDF template how you want it to look and populate it with data (using something like iTextSharp) before returning the file contents to the client." How?

Comment: @JimBarton: You might use something like Acrobat or even just Word (printing to a PDF file) to design the initial PDF.  (I don't have a lot of experience with creating PDF files, only populating them with data.)  You'd leave empty spaces where the data would go and then use iTextSharp to dynamically fill in that data.  The latter can end up being a bit of a trial-and-error process to get elements aligned properly, and there may be multiple techniques to make that work.  I've never found much helpful tooling online for this, it's mostly just tweaking the element layout until it looks right.

Comment: You could also use XSL FO server side through a SOAP interface. Very easy to submit structured data and format to PDF results and return the PDF byte stream to the browser.